# Gunicorn APPMODULE

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my Django project via gunicorn, but I'm having trouble deciphering what APPMODULE refers to:

```
$(MODULE_NAME):$(VARIABLE_NAME)
```

What does Module_Name and Variable_NAME refer to in the context of a Django project named "stats"? Thanks!

Comment: What is the context of this? Where did you see this reference?

Answer (score 0):

in /project/ there is a wsgi.py. $(MODULE_NAME):$(VARIABLE_NAME) should be set to `projectnname.wsgi:application`

from my gunicorn_start file for [shtuff.it](https://shtuff.it):

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=shtuffit.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=shtuffit.wsgi
... 
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application ...
```